# Exception: wrong output

Tags: c++, exception

```
int At(int i, int j) const {
    try {
        if (i >= m.size() || j >= m[0].size())
            throw out_of_range("out_of_range");
        return m.at(i).at(j);
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

int& At(int i, int j) {
    try {
        if (i >= m.size() || j >= m[0].size())
            throw out_of_range("out_of_range");
        return m.at(i).at(j);
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
Matrix one, two(2, 3);
cout << two;
one.Reset(0, 0);
cout << one.At(4, 4);
return 0;
}
```

in this code must be printed exception: out_of_range, but in my case it is :
out_of_range
-244281
What are this number and how can I remove it from output?

Comment: Can you show us the vomplete `Matrix` class please?

Comment: Seems like `j >= m[0].size()` should be `j >= m[i].size()`. In any case, why check the bounds yourself? You use `at` which will `throw std::out_of_range` if the index is out of bounds anyway.

Comment: When you `catch` your function doesn't return anything which is Undefined Behavior. Since there is nothing you can return, the correct course of action is probably to `throw`. Catching the exception here is detrimental.

Comment: You are doing it totally wrong. Exceptions are meant to be thrown *out* of functions. You don't need them thrown and caught *within* a ten-line function. You could just as well use `if`. `if (i < m.size() && j < m[i].size()) return m.at(i).at(j); else` (do what exactly?)

Comment: main function is here to prove that class works correctly. and is works ,how i want (mostly), but at the end it prints a number. I do not need this number. how can i remove it

Comment: The class doesn't work correctly.  The correct action is to throw an exception *out*. You cannot write a correctly working class that doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

If the exception is thrown, then the `catch` handler prints the message (`"out_of_range"`) and then the function continues on like nothing happened.

The problem is that this "continue on" leads to the functions ending without you returning anything, leading to *undefined behavior* when you try to print this non-return value.

If you declare a function to return anything, the you *must* return something.

---

With that said, catching the exception in the `At` function makes no sense. And considering that one of the variants return a reference, it's very hard to return a "value" since you can't have "null" references.

The solution then is not to have the `try-catch` at all in the functions, but let the *caller* of the function handle any possible exception.

Answer (score 4):

```
int& At(int i, int j) {
   // ...
   catch (exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

The exception is caught and printed ...and then `At()` returns normally.

Your compiler should've warned you about returning from a non-void function without returning a value.

In your `main()`:

```
cout << one.At(4, 4);
```

So, now this attempts to interpreted the value returned from `At()` as a reference to some `int`. Nothing was returned, so this is undefined behavior, and you can get any random junk printed here. Or your program can crash. You have no logical expectations, any more.